# GDB scripting: check which function is running

Tags: gdb

I'm writing a GDB script to walk the stack and inspect certain local variables only if the function running at that stack level is a specific one. How can I programatically check which function is running at each level? "backtrace" shows what I want. I just need it in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want in GDB 7.3, which has Python scripting and [exposed stack frame info](http://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Frames-In-Python.html) to the Python interpreter.